# concatentate values in GNU Make

Tags: makefile, gnu, string-concatenation

In bash I can easily concatenate multiple values.

```
$ VERSION=0.1.$(date +%s)-$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
$ echo $VERSION
0.1.1429307021-6206daa
```

How do I assign a value like this in GNU Make? The [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Appending.html) on strings only addresses simple cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is to use make's [`shell` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html) to run your shell commands, like this:

```
VERSION := 0.1.$(shell date +%s)-$(shell git rev-parse --short HEAD)
```

This works similarly to the shell's backticks or `$()` feature.

Makefiles have different syntax than shell scripts, so you can't always use shell syntax unmodified.  In particular, the `$` character is special to make, so anywhere in a recipe that would use a dollar sign you have to escape it from make so it is passed through to the shell.  If you wanted to use pure shell solution rather than make functions you can use old-school backticks in your command line:

```
VERSION := 0.1.`date +%s`-`git rev-parse --short HEAD`
```

If you want to use the new `$()` syntax you must [escape the `$`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables-in-Recipes.html) like this:

```
VERSION := 0.1.$$(date +%s)-$$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
```

Note that there are deeper differences between the first solution (using a make function) and the latter two: in the first make runs the commands itself and sees the real value of the variable internally.  In the latter two the value of make's `VERSION` variable is just the string containing the shell commands, which make passes to the shell in a recipe and the shell will run the commands.

Comment: That did it. Thanks for answering in spite of my hyperbole. I'll tone it down for perpetuates sake.